# Error message when building for simulator in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Error message when building for simulator in Xcode 8.

Using `stringWithString:` with a literal is redundant

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"]
                           dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question, even?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you can simply write it as:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Using `NSString stringWithString` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal string

```
 [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```